# Which jar will have org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase class?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I was trying to connect HBase from Spark using shc. But while running the below code I am getting an error "Failed to find data source: **org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase**" Please help me with the jar which has this class ?

My data_source_format = "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase"

```
df.write.options(catalog=catalog).option('catalog', catalog).format(data_source_format).save()
```

Comment: That's a package, not a class, and the SHC package does... Looks like you've not configured it correctly

Comment: I am using **shc-core-1.1.1-1.6-s_2.10.jar** but I can't see the class in this package

Comment: You need to include `--packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11` at spark submit